# If x and y are uncorrelated with z, does is follow that x/y uncorrelated with z?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

In other words, if the Pearson r between x and z, and between y and z, is zero, does it follow that x/y is uncorrelated with z?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes, Pearson's $r$  is the correlation (or rather, we're discussing random variables, so we're talking about population correlation, $\rho$). If $\rho\neq 0$ then the variables are correlated, but the title and the body text still ask distinctly different questions. Please clarify which one is to be answered. I believe a quick, clear answer to the title question is possible (so I suggest modifying the body), but if you require an answer to the body question instead, modify the title.

Comment: if we can't say it's uncorrelated that doesn't mean we couldn't say *something*. The first question could be answered in the negative simply by an example where the correlation is nonzero, but the second question (essentially, needing an answer to *what things can we say about the correlation*) would seem to require something approaching a characterization of the ways the correlation would or would not be zero; a considerably larger task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, here is a counter example:

$P(y = 1) = P(y = -1) = 0.5, ~ x = z y$ with $P(z = 1) = P(z = 2) = 0.5$ and $z$ independent of $y$. Since $z = x/y$, $z$ and $x/y$ are perfectly correlated. However, $z$ and $y$ are independent, therefore they are clearly uncorrelated.
Finally:
Cov(x,z) = $\mathbb{E} (xz) - \mathbb{E}(x) \mathbb{E}(z)$ with the expected value of $x$ being 0 and $\mathbb{E} (xz) = \mathbb{E} (yz^2) = \mathbb{E} (y) \mathbb{E} (z^2) = 0$ because the expected value of $y$ is again 0